# does apple allow ios applications to get user location by IP address

Tags: ios, permissions, location, ip

does apple allow ios applications to get user location by IP address?

I use Wipmania to get user current location:

```
 NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://api.wipmania.com/json?callback=?"];
```

if not, could I ask user for a permission to access their current location data?

I don't need any other geolocation information, all what i need is the country they are accessing the internet from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is any restriction on getting the country based on IP. you can always ask the user for permission, either for this technique and / or to use the GPS.

Note that with the IP technique VPN connections will have an influence.